# How to check a collection is not null and elements in collection are also not null

Tags: java

I get is null using apache collections utils in java 8:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(reportEnvelopeApps)) {

}
```

But if the collection reportEnvelopeApps contains one element null, It works unexpectedly. So I have to write code like this:

```
        if (reportEnvelopeApps == null) {
            return null;
        }
        reportEnvelopeApps.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(reportEnvelopeApps)) {
            return null;
        }
```

What is the better way to avoid bad code like this?

Comment: Removing is an unefficient way. Try to loop in that collection and if any element is null, just continue that one.

Comment: it's not bad code (i don't see in what case your second approach will fail), you may wrap it into an abstraction (e.g: a function) so your code looks cleaner. Do you need to clean the collection or to return a null if the collection isNullOrhasAllNullsOrIsEmpty?

Comment: try to use Optional keyword in Java 8 instead of using null.  Optional is introduced to avoid code smells due to null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Optional` and return list with only non null elements or else return `null`

```
List<String> res = Optional.ofNullable(reportEnvelopeApps)
            .map(list->list.removeIf(Objects::isNull) ? list : list)
            .filter(list->!list.isEmpty())
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Isn't wrapping of `Collection` object to `Optional` generally unadvised for `null` denotation? Optional usually contains a result that is a value and not a container.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap this in a utility method

```
public (static) List<String> removeNull(List<String> orig){
  if(orig==null){
     return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  return orig.stream.filter(x->x!=null).collect(Collectors.toList);
}
```

You can put that in your own CollectionUtil/ListUtil class or somewhere else where you can easily re-use it. Your main code then just applies the filter method and checks whether the list has any values. If at all necessary - at best you simply have code that iterates over the list, making special case handling for null/empty list obsolete.

If you really care for speed, you might just hand around streams instead of collections, that would avoid the copy that is being created here, but in most cases that is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all possible non-null elements to a new list, using `Stream`, after `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(reportEnvelopeApps)`

```
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(reportEnvelopeApps)) {
    List<ReportEnvelope> nonNullList = reportEnvelopeApps
                                          .stream()
                                          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
     // Proceed with whatever needs to be done with the new list.        
    }
```